# Using a keystroke to repeat a function

Tags: python, python-2.7, keystroke

I have a backup script that simply runs every day and backs up files to a directory if they exist in source dir but not in destination dir.

Sometimes (rarely) the script will fall over if a file isn't permissioned properly.

I've got around this using a `try/except` block.

However what I want to do now is to display the error message from the `except` block and then to say

```
>>> Press Enter to re-run backup
```

and then for the script to re-run the copying process which is a defined function.

So to summarise:

1. Script runs
2. Script throws error
3. User follows instructions from error message
4. User presses "Enter" key to re-run the copying function

I am running windows if that makes a difference (when I was googling this problem a lot of the results were to do with python on windows)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python read a single character from the user](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user)

Comment: Not a duplicate. The keystroke isn't the main part of my question. Moreso the recognition of that keystroke to re-run a function once an error message is shown.Although people reading this question might find that question useful as well, so thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `raw_input()` (or simply `input()` if using Python 3) to wait for `Enter` and a condition variable to control looping through the copying process until successful.

```
from sys import stderr

def run_backup():
    print "running backup"
    raise  # this simulates an error


backup_completed = False

while not backup_completed:
    try:
        run_backup()
        backup_completed = True
    except:
        print >> stderr, "Error message..."
        raw_input(">>> Press Enter to re-run backup")
```

Comment: Will this re-run the script though. I think I understand what you've written in terms of the error etc. but on the enter keystroke does this repeat `run_backup`

Comment: It will call again `run_backup()`.  Is this not the expected behaviour?

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted. I'm just a bit new to python and still learning some stuff so wasn't 100% sure it'd do this.

Comment: That's great :)  As you can see, the `raise` in the `run_backup()` function is just there to simulate an error condition.  Also, an this answer be correct, please accept it, so that it may be useful for others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Seems pretty simple to me. You can just use `raw_input` to make the script wait an Enter key-press:

```
while True:
    try:
        # run the script
    except SomeException as e:
        # print the error message and recovery instructions

        raw_input('Press Enter to re-run backup.')
```